# how do I only show the "arrow" in a HTML select element?

Tags: html

Basically, I want to be able to just show the drop-down arrow and not the text-box associated to that drop-down arrow. I don't want to display the value, but the javascript onchange event will still fire if someone changes the selection.

Idea's?

Paul

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Your question seems a little odd to me, maybe we can help you to find a more "normal" solution if you provide some details.

Comment: Don't know if you've gotten past this yet, but I created a select tag and gave it a width of 28px and set the first option as a space. It's still ugly. :/ I'm working on using a CSS down-arrow and putting an onClick onto it that will trigger the select event.

Answer (score 6):

## Solution for Chrome only

(maybe webkit in general, but I can't test that)

I tried it in old IE7/8, doesn't work because it cuts off the dropdown to the set width as well.
Firefox doesn't show the arrow and instead cuts the text off since it left-aligns.

### Solution is as follows:

Should be pretty easy to just set the width of the control via CSS and limit it to the arrow. Simple example I built for Chrome (doesn't really work in other browsers):

```
​<select style="width:18px">
    <option value="10000">Something</option>
    <option value="100">Other thing</option>
    <option value="1">The last option</option>
</select>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fs7G5/

Comment: I should have qualified this and indicated that it has to work in other browsers as well, namely, IE8,IE9.

Comment: Basically works in Firefox also if you set the width to 19px and set `border-style:none`.

Comment: I did use `width:1.5em;` and worked fine in firefox.  this is a great question and a great answer

Answer (score -1):

```
 <select><option></select>
```

It does not make much sense, but it answers the question asked.

Comment: I uhh, don't think that answers the question. The request is for a drowndown box that doesn't display the selected option and is just an arrow. Then when you click that the selections drop down and you can see them.

Comment: @TheZ, the question was about “to just show the drop-down arrow” and “I don't want to display the value”. Even when you click on the arrow, no value is shown. But it would be more interesting to know what the purpose is here. (And how is the user expected to change selection without seeing the options?)

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting. It shouldn't display a value when it's just on the page, but when a user clicks on it they should get the full dropdown with the list of options to satisfy the "javascript onchange event will still fire if someone changes the selection" bit. It's just poorly worded?

Comment: @TheZ, that might be the intent, but it was not the question asked. Triggering an unspecified JavaScript event has nothing to do with the opening of a menu. But I’m more interested in what might possibly be the justification for requesting such horrible lack of usability.

Answer (score -1):

You will not find a cross-browser solution. You probably will want to set all appearances across all browsers to none, and then build a custom-styled select/option that works to meet your requirements. The JS onchange event will still fire properly even if it has a custom style.

You can read up on [`appearance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance) at the MDN, but note that it isn't supported fully. An example you can utilize for the time being:

`appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;`

You will need to adjust properties such as `border`, `border-radius`, and `background-color` if you try to style your own solution.